# Set refresh rate on tables in power bi desktop created from log analytic queries

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have created a report in power Bi desktop and in that report i have imported data from Log analytics in Azure, using exported m-language queries for each table.

Is there any way to set the refresh rate for each table/data set or something a like? I want the report to display some what live data.

**EDIT:**

[image: Picture in response to WimV's answer.]

Comment: If you want to show live data, you can use streaming datasets. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-real-time-streaming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power bi desktop is a business intelligence tool, and reports in Power BI  can be refreshed manual, or scheduled in power BI service.
Once you publish to powerbi.com you can setup the refresh frequency based on your source files.

[image: premium vs pro]
[premium capacity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-premium)

When using PowerBI PRO as license type, then you have a limit of 8 refreshes a day. Premium capacity can have up to 48 automatic refresh.

When you need more up to date data, or don't want to pay for premium capacity. You can store your data in an azure sql database, and use direct query to get your data.

Comment: Thanks for you answer @WimV. 
Yes, i was that documentation but i could only refresh and set refresh-triggers up to 8 times a day every hour or half an hour, not 15 minutes as the guide shows... referring to the edited part of the post (look at picture).

Comment: hmm i found th api call for refreshs (i think), https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/refreshdataset. Would it be the same limit of refresh rate if i where to update the report by calls?